# loop the id in selenium python

Tags: python, loops, selenium, getelementbyid

i have script to select the button like below

```
driver.find_element_by_id("Product").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("id1").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("id1").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("id2").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("id2").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("id3").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("id3").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("id4").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("id4").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("id5").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("id5").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("id6").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("id6").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("id7").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("id7").click()
```

so here i am selection the button product and then it has multiple items.
each code will select the product and deselect it

How can loop this id selections instead writing long script
like once product button selected then a loop to select all the items in the product

Comment: Use `for` loop? `for i in range(1, 9): driver.find_element_by_id("id{}".format(i)).click()`

Answer (score 0):

This can reduce your code and you can use appropriate range required.

```
driver.find_element_by_id("Product").click()
for element_id in range(1, 8):
    id = "id{}".format(element_id)
    driver.find_element_by_id(id).click()
    driver.find_element_by_id(id).click()
```

Comment: OP requested each click to be done twice. You will need to repeat the last line.

Comment: i am getting this error
Name error "driver" is not found

Comment: script runs without any error. but its not selecting the button

Answer (score 0):

@COLDSPEED 's comment points us to the right direction where as @VaibhavMule 's answer was near perfect but none of them considered the impact of `click()` from **`Selenium`** perspective.

### **click()**

**click()** would interact with a document through the **`selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement`** interface.

So **click()** method call will do a freshness check to ensure that the element reference is still valid. This essentially determines whether or not the element is still attached to the DOM. If this test fails, then an **`StaleElementReferenceException`** is thrown, and all future calls to this instance will fail. Hence before invoking each `click()` we have to induce **`WebDriverWait`** with `expected_conditions` clause set to **`element_to_be_clickable`**.

So to `loop this id selections` to `select and deselect them`, you can use the following code block :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.find_element_by_id("Product").click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "id1")))
for id in range(1, 7):
    my_id = "my_id{}".format(id)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "my_id"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "my_id"))).click()
```

Comment: same error
NameError: name 'WebDriverWait' is not defined

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import unittest, re
import time

i am missing some thing

Comment: script runs without any error. but its not selecting the button

Comment: Thats because you were not able to identify the element properly. Share the relevant HTML

Comment: this is the out put trace

WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "my_id"))).click()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
TimeoutException: Message: